# How to generate word file from html code using phpword and keeping source formatting

Tags: phpword

I am using ckeditor to save the contents of a word document in my database in html format. Now when I convert the html content from my database to docx while using phpword, I have the word document which is generating fine but the formatting is completely lost.
Help months please.
I am using symfony3.4

Comment: Why you just save the document as its original format in the database instead? Saving as a blob will save the conversion pain back and forward...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact it is not exactly the original document which is saved in the database. the user makes some modification before saving the content in the database. And I save the raw html code to be able to use it with phpword to generate the content in word